# $C$ is a square matrix and $\operatorname{tr}(C)=0$ are there matrices $A$ and $B$ in which $C=AB-BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$C$ is a square matrix and $\operatorname{tr}(C)=0$ are there matrices $A$ and $B$ in which $C=AB-BA$? I was thinking about the *skew-symmetric* matrix definition in which $A^T=-A$ so $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$ .Anyways, I cannot sketch any sort of proof on a paper.

Comment: Over which field are these matrices?